# why apache rewrite directories that not exists to php files

Tags: apache

I have a problem with my apache. I have test.php on domain.com website that will targeted by domain.com/test.php now when I run domain.com/test/sometext/ it must show 404 Not Found status, but it run test.php. how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews